# JQuery :: retrieve values from form elements

Tags: jquery, html, tags, hidden

I've wrote a html page wich uses jquery, but javascript execution stops at the following point:

```
alert($('[name=fAantalVakjes]').val());
```

This is the relevant html tag:

```
<input type="hidden" value="1" id="fAantalVakjes" name="fAantalVakjes" />
```

Could someone help me please?

Thanks in advance,

Yvan
Edit: full code:

```
function ValidateOnderzoeksRechter() {
    var or1, or2, or3, totaalOR;
    var blnReturn = true;
    or1 = $('#fOnderzoeksrechter_1').attr('value');
    or2 = $('#fOnderzoeksrechter_2').attr('value');
    or3 = $('#fOnderzoeksrechter_3').attr('value');

    if ((or1.length == 2)) {
        // ok
        setColor('fOnderzoeksrechter_1',true);
    } else {
        // NOT OK
        setColor('fOnderzoeksrechter_1',false);
        blnReturn = false;
    }

    if ((or2.length <= 7) && (or2.length >= 1)) {
        // ok
        setColor('fOnderzoeksrechter_2',true);
    } else {
        // NOT OK
        setColor('fOnderzoeksrechter_2',false);
        blnReturn = false;
    }

    if ((or3.length == 2)) {
        // ok
        setColor('fOnderzoeksrechter_3',true);
    } else {
        // NOT OK
        setColor('fOnderzoeksrechter_3',false);
        blnReturn = false;
    }

    $('#fOnderzoeksrechter_1').val((or1.toUpperCase()));
    $('#fOnderzoeksrechter_2').val((or2.toUpperCase()));
    $('#fOnderzoeksrechter_3').val((or3.toUpperCase()));

    if (blnReturn) {
        //$('#message').html('Gelieve de rode vakjes te corrigeren.');
    }

    return blnReturn;
}

function ValidateParketNr() {
    var parket1, parket2, parket3, parket4, parket5, totaalParket;
    parket1 = $('#fParket1').attr('value');
    parket2 = $('#fParket2').attr('value');
    parket3 = $('#fParket3').attr('value');
    parket4 = $('#fParket4').attr('value');
    parket5 = $('#fParket5').attr('value');



    var blnReturn;
    blnReturn = true;
    if ((parket1.length == 2)) {
        // ok
        setColor('fParket1',true);
    } else {
        // NOT OK
        setColor('fParket1',false);
        blnReturn = false;
    }
    if ((parket2.length == 2)) {
        // ok
        setColor('fParket2',true);
    } else {
        // NOT OK
        setColor('fParket2',false);
        blnReturn = false;
    }
    if ((parket3.length == 2)) {
        // ok
        setColor('fParket3',true);
    } else {
        // NOT OK
        setColor('fParket3',false);
        blnReturn = false;
    }
    if (IsNumeric(parket4) && (parket4.length) <= 7 && (parket4.length) >= 1) {
        // ok
        setColor('fParket4',true);
    } else {
        // NOT OK
        setColor('fParket4',false);
        blnReturn = false;
    }
    if (IsNumeric(parket5) && (parket5.length) == 2) {
        // ok
        setColor('fParket5',true);
    } else {
        // NOT OK
        setColor('fParket5',false);
        blnReturn = false;
    }



    $('#fParket1').val((parket1.toUpperCase()));
    $('#fParket2').val((parket2.toUpperCase()));
    $('#fParket3').val((parket3.toUpperCase()));

    if (blnReturn) {
        //$('#message').html('Gelieve de rode vakjes te corrigeren.');
    }

    return blnReturn;
}

function IsNumeric(sText)
{
    if (sText != null) {

       var ValidChars = "0123456789.";
       var IsNumber=true;
       var Char;
       for (i = 0; i < sText.length && IsNumber == true; i++) 
          { 
          Char = sText.charAt(i); 
          if (ValidChars.indexOf(Char) == -1) 
             {
             IsNumber = false;
             }
          }
        return IsNumber;
    } else {
        return false;
    }


}

function setColor(naam ,blnOK) {
    if(blnOK) {
        $('#' + naam).css('background-color', '#00ff00');

    } else {
        $('#' + naam).css('background-color', '#ff0000');
    }
}

function ValidateForm() {

    var blnResult;
    blnResult = true;
    if(!orIsLeeg()) {

        blnResult = ValidateOnderzoeksRechter();
    }
    if (!ParketIsLeeg()) {
        blnResult = ValidateParketNr();
    }


    blnResult = ValideerRestVanFormulier();
    return blnResult;
}

function XOR(b1, b2) {
    return (!b1 && b2) || (b1 && !b2);
}

function orIsLeeg() {
    var ISLEEG;
    ISLEEG = true;
    for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++){
        if ($('#fOnderzoeksrechter_' + (x + 1)).val != '') {
            ISLEEG = false;
        }
    }   
    return ISLEEG;
}

function ParketIsLeeg() {
    var ISLEEG;
    ISLEEG = true;
    for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++){
        if ($('#fParket' + (x + 1)).val != '') {
            ISLEEG = false;
        }
    }   
    return ISLEEG;
}

function ValideerRestVanFormulier() {
    var ret, value;
    ret = true;
    ret = ValideerCijfer('fAantalMaatregelen');
    ret = ValideerCijfer('fAantalOnderzoeken');
    ret = ValideerCijfer('fAantalBetrokkenVerdachten');
    ret = ValideerCijfer('fAantalNuttig');


    for (var x = 0; x < AANTAL_VAKJES ; x++){
        ret = ValideerCijfer('fFeitAantal' + x);
    }

    return ret;
}

function ValideerCijfer(veld) {
    try {
        if (IsNumeric($("#"  + veld).val()) && ($("#"  + veld).val() != '')) {
            setColor(veld, true);
            return true;
        } else {
            setColor(veld, false);
            return false;   
        }
    } catch (ex) {
        alert(ex);
    }
}
```

The function is called from this element:

```
<input type="text" onchange="ValideerRestVanFormulier()" value="" name="fFeitAantal0" />
```

The following code outputs 'sText undefined':

```
function ValideerCijfer(veld) {
    try {
        if (IsNumeric($("#"  + veld).val()) && ($("#"  + veld).val() != '')) {
            setColor(veld, true);
            return true;
        } else {
            setColor(veld, false);
            return false;   
        }
    } catch (ex) {
        alert(ex);
    }
}
```

See the isNumeric function above...

Here's a short explanation of the function names (they're dutch)
ValideerCijfer = validateNumber --> A function used to check if it's a valid number.

Comment: Your expression *should* work. Have you enclosed that line within a `$(document).ready(...` block?

Comment: Not the full code?  I get "IsNumeric is not defined".

Comment: Sorry, forgot to copy that...

Comment: Try enclosing the "value = $('[name="fAantalVakjes"]').val()" in a try /catch and see if it throws an error. Also try to alert (or use firebug's console.log()) and trace $('[name="fAantalVakjes"]').length

Comment: I just ran you code. It alert "1" just fine. I had to comment out "ValideerCijfer" (4 lines). Since i don't know what's in them. Perhaps it's those who generates an error. Tried both jQuery 1.3.2 and 1.4

Comment: Yeah, it runs for me, too (after commenting out the same 4 lines of code.

Comment: altered my code above, and finally got an error message. See my text for more info...

Comment: You missed `setColor` too.  :p  But the code works without it.

Comment: I've added this already- now it's the full javascript file. This might be confusing, because almost everything is dutch...

Comment: I copied your script, added `<input>` elements for "fParket", "fOnderzoeksrechter", etc., assigned `AANTAL_VAKJES = 0`, and it works for me.  The fields `fAantalMaatregelen`, `fAantalOnderzoeken`, `fAantalBetrokkenVerdachten` and `fAantalNuttig` turn red or green, when I change the value for `fFeitAantal0` (and go out of focus).

Comment: BTW, your statement `alert($('[name=fAantalVakjes]').val());` is missing in your "full code".

Comment: I put my test HTML file here: http://necramirez.info/index.html -- when I type something in the last field "fFeitAantal0" and click somewhere else in the page, the previous 4 fields change background-color.

Comment: Found the problem already... Forgot to specify the ID field in fAantalVakjes.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem myself: I forgot to specify an ID to the fAantalVakjes field...

Thanks for the help!

Yvan

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the Id selector instead ?

```
$('#fAantalVakjes').val()
```

Or using the name:

```
$('[name="fAantalVakjes"]').val()
```

..fredrik

Comment: Nope, doesn't work...
Tried  
var value;
value = $('#fAantalVakjes').val(); // gets stuck here
alert(value);
It gets stuck with the second rule. I'm using the FireBug extension to determine that.

Answer (score 0):

As Karim points out in his comment, the problem might be that your code is executed before the DOM is fully loaded. Usually, most jQuery code is placed within a `$(document).ready()` callback, ensuring that the DOM is available when executing. Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($('[name=fAantalVakjes]').val());
});
```

As Fredrik mentions in his answer, you might want to consider using the `id` attribute of your `<input>` element instead, as it provides easier (and often more reliable) selection:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($('#fAantalVakjes').val());
});
```

Comment: that's not what I need... I've added extra info :)

Comment: This code does work though, but I can't do anything with it.
I know the page is succesfuly loaded, because the function is called after you've entered something.

Answer (score 0):

This MIGHT seem obvious, but does your input tag have a closure in the HTML `</input>`

Try changing

```
 value = $('[name="fAantalVakjes"]').val();
```

to be

```
 value = $('input[name="fAantalVakjes"]').val();
```

EDIT: OH, and DO use the ID instead for speed, I did not include that as I do not know the rest of your circumstances.

EDIT2: just one other thought, I don't really like the "value" name.  I would change it to something else like:

```
myvalue = $('input[name="fAantalVakjes"]').val();
alert(myvalue);
```

Comment: this is copyed from the debugger, the real tag has it